# upsert-kafka connect in flink produces null in the final topic

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have a sql defined this way

```
  
CREATE TABLE raw_table
(
    headers     VARCHAR,
    id          VARCHAR,
    type        VARCHAR,
    contentJson VARCHAR
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'kafka',
      'topic-pattern' = 'role__.+?',
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:29092,localhost:39092',
      'properties.group.id' = 'role_local_1',
      'scan.startup.mode' = 'earliest-offset',
      'format' = 'json',
      'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',
      'json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
      'sink.parallelism' = '3'
      );

create view ROLES_NORMALIZED as
(
select 
       JSON_VALUE(contentJson, '$.id')                                 as id,
       rr.type                                                         as type
from raw_table rr
    );



CREATE VIEW ROLES_UPSERTS_V1 AS
(
SELECT *
FROM ROLES_NORMALIZED
WHERE type in ('ROLE_CREATED', 'ROLE_UPDATED')
    );


CREATE VIEW ROLES_DELETED_V1 AS
(
SELECT org,
       pod,
       tenantId,
       id,
       modified,
       modified as deleted,
       event_timestamp
FROM ROLES_NORMALIZED
WHERE type in ('ROLES_DELETED')
    );

-------


CREATE TABLE final_topic
(
    event_timestamp         TIMESTAMP_LTZ,
    id                      VARCHAR,
    name                    VARCHAR,
    deleted                 TIMESTAMP_LTZ,
    PRIMARY KEY (pod, org, id) NOT ENFORCED
) WITH (
      'connector' = 'upsert-kafka',
      'topic' = 'final_topic',
      'properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'localhost:29092,localhost:39092',
      'properties.group.id' = 'some-group-id',
      'value.format' = 'json',
      'key.format' = 'json',
      'properties.allow.auto.create.topics' = 'true',
      'properties.replication.factor' = '3',
      'value.json.timestamp-format.standard' = 'ISO-8601',
      'sink.parallelism' = '3'
      );


INSERT INTO final_topic
select 
       GREATEST(r.event_timestamp, d.event_timestamp) as event_timestamp,
       r.id,
       r.name,
       d.deleted
from ROLES_UPSERTS_V1 r
         LEFT JOIN ROLES_DELETED_V1 d
                   ON r.id = d.id;
```

The `final_topic` is produces the result i want to see, which is join of `ROLES_UPSERTS_V1` and `ROLES_DELETED_V1`.

I tried this by publishing records to `role__.+?` topic.

What I am observing is that `final-topic` has `null` values as well. This is emitted when even the changelog kind happens to be `-d` `-(DELETE)`. I understand the purpose as to why this exist. (here its saying the original message needs to be deleted and new one will follow). But I dont want such `null` values in my `final-topic` just the desired final state is this possible ?

Alternate that I am trying is to use `Kafka` connector. But the joins does not seems to work, as i get an error saying `org.apache.flink.table.api.TableException: Table sink 'default_catalog.default_database.final_topic' doesn't support consuming update and delete changes which is produced by node Join(joinType=[LeftOuterJoin]`. I get error when i use `view` for `ROLES_UPSERTS_V1` and `ROLES_DELETED_V1` . But if i have these as tables (with kafka connector) only inner join works ( left join does not work).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want `null` values, you can consider buffering records before you flush the results to the Upsert Kafka connector. See https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/connectors/table/upsert-kafka/#sink-buffer-flush-max-rows for more details

Regarding your join, as [outlined in the docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/table/sql/queries/joins/#regular-joins) `For streaming queries, the grammar of regular joins is the most flexible and allow for any kind of updating (insert, update, delete) input table.` Since you're running a streaming query, a future change could mean that the result of your join os an update or a delete. However, the sink that you're trying to emit to does not support this, hence the error.

Comment: I tried adding 
`'sink.buffer-flush.max-rows' = '10','sink.buffer-flush.interval' = '1000'`

I get an error 

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.table.ReducingUpsertWriter.flush(ReducingUpsertWriter.java:145)```

When i look at the `ReducingUpsertWriter.java:145` it seems to doing `wrappedContext.setTimestamp(value.f1);` Here the `value` is null.

How do i get around this ?

Comment: Are you sure you're using the latest Flink version?

Comment: I am using 1.16.0

Comment: Can you create a Flink Jira ticket for the null pointer exception?

Comment: Sure, let me create one

Comment: Martijn Visser , seems like the null pointer exception is coming from this line `wrappedContext.setTimestamp(value.f1);` Here `value.f1` is null. When emitting a message how to set a timestamp ?